# How to implement `final` semantics pre C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, final

C++11 introduced the `final` specifier, which allows a base class to prevent derivation or overriding of virtual functions in derived classes.

How can I enforce similar constraints on class inheritance and function overriding pre C++11?

Comment: https://github.com/boostorg/config/blob/601598f8325350acb0c905d8f3293c17ae61cae3/include/boost/config/detail/suffix.hpp#L1001

Comment: The paper proposing the idea https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1827.htm .  Note it does not propose the final syntax but does outline the motivation.  See the links from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/11 (search for "final") for the final syntax

Comment: Why? Code that works correctly with `final` will also work correctly without it. `final` is one of many nanny techniques that allow designers to tell users that they have to do things in a particular way, because, after all, I'm the designer and you're just a user, and nobody could think of a way of using my classes that's different from what I had in mind.

Comment: @PeteBecker an interesting discussion but off-topic for this question, which is about "how" rather than "why"

Comment: @JeremyFriesner -- "don't bother" is always a legitimate answer to "how do I do this complicated thing". Which is also a valid answer after `final` was added. <g>

Comment: Not only is C++11 a well-established standard, but so is C++14, C++17 and C++20. Asking about C++98 really should go to RetroComputing.SE by now, it's a quarter century ago.

Comment: @MSalters "Asking about C++98 really should go to RetroComputing" I wish. In practice it's there to stay and none of us can do anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Best I can suggest is making the constructor private and enforcing a factory function for instantiation:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static Foo* makeInstance(int initialX)
    {
        return new Foo(initialX);
    }


private:
    Foo(int initialX) :x(initialX) {}
    int x;
    int setX(int value) { x = value; }
    int getX() { return x; }
};
```

That should prevent inheritance. But it does require your callers to explicitly instantiate the object via the static `makeInstance` function or similar. And then explicitly delete it.

You can also have it return the object copy instead of by pointer.

```
static Foo makeInstance(int initialX)
{
    return Foo(initialX);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Making the class behave somewhat like "final" can be achieved using virtual inheritance and class friendship.

Personally I would not recommend using it in this manner, but it's certainly possible.

```cpp
class seal
{
    friend class impl1;
    friend class impl2;
    seal() {} // note it's private!
};

struct interface
{
    virtual ~interface() {}
};

struct impl1 : interface, virtual seal
{};

struct impl2 : interface, virtual seal
{};


struct impl3 : impl2{}; // declaration works...

int main()
{
    impl1 i1;
    impl2 i2;
    impl3 i3; // ...but fails to compile here
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/MjKhbaTo8